# Which x86 CPUID return values cannot be changed on a processor?

Tags: x86, cpuid

I know that the Name String on some AMD processors can be changed to return a different string. I believe the BIOS can disable cache or SSE support which would necessitate that the bits that indicate cache/SSE support would have to return different values.

Which values returned by the CPUID instruction are guaranteed to never change on a given CPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats incredibly generic, as CPU's tend to change over time and they differ between brands, you are better off using the CPUID manuals/specs from [AMD](http://support.amd.com/us/Embedded_TechDocs/25481.pdf) and [Intel](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/doc/application-note/processor-identification-cpuid-instruction-note.pdf), supplemented with the data from their respective developer manuals.

You'll probably find that the model and family related stuff is constant, along with a lot of the topological features.

Comment: Yes, it would seem reasonable that the signature (family/model/stepping number) should at least return the same values always for a given CPU. It also seems like the features should be constant, otherwise software that detects them when installing would have no guarantees. I asked hoping someone more knowledgeable than me could save me from delving through the manuals.